# Validate format of the string typed in gtk_entry

Tags: c, string, function

I need to write a function that will validate device name typed by user in gtk entry field.

Device must be in the following form:

```
"/dev/video + one digits" ( e.g. /dev/video1 )
```

For this I made function but I don't now how to write condition

```
void validate_device_cb (GtkEntry* entry, const gchar* text,
                         gint length, gint* position, gpointer data)
{
    GtkEditable *editable = GTK_EDITABLE (entry);
    int i, count = 0;
    gchar *result = g_new (gchar, length);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            /* insert condition here */

                    continue;
            result[count++] = text[i];
    }

    if (count > 0) {
            g_signal_handlers_block_by_func (G_OBJECT (editable),
                            G_CALLBACK (validate_device_cb), data);
            gtk_editable_insert_text (editable, result, count, position);
            g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func (G_OBJECT (editable),
                            G_CALLBACK (validate_device_cb), data);
    }
    g_signal_stop_emission_by_name (G_OBJECT (editable), "insert_text");

    g_free (result);
}
```

Any help are welcome
Best regards

UPDATE ( more explication)

gtk entry must should accept only this  chars typed:

```
first typed: '/'
second       'd'
third        'e'
fourth       'v'
fifth        '/'
sixth        'v'
seventh      'i'
eight        'd'  
.........
eleven        digit
twelve        digit
```

setting device entry:

```
video_device = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(12);
gtk_editable_set_editable(GTK_EDITABLE(video_device),TRUE);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(video_device), "insert_text" ,
                          G_CALLBACK(validate_device_cb), NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check that the string starts with `/dev/video` (`strstr`) and then check that the characters after `strlen('/dev/video')` are all digits (`isdigit`).

A better solution is to reread the string using `sscanf` and a format specifier and check if all format specifiers have been matched.

**Example**: see the following code which tests if 4 strings, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` have the required format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "/dev/video42";
    char b[] = "a random string";
    char c[] = "/dev/video"; /* no number at the end */
    char d[] = "/dev/video/something_else";

    /* test variables */
    int n;
    int result;

    /* test for a */
    result = sscanf(a, "/dev/video%d", &n);
    printf("Result for a=%d\n", result);

    /* test for b */
    result = sscanf(b, "/dev/video%d", &n);
    printf("Result for b=%d\n", result);

    /* test for c */
    result = sscanf(c, "/dev/video%d", &n);
    printf("Result for c=%d\n", result);

    /* test for d */
    result = sscanf(d, "/dev/video%d", &n);
    printf("Result for d=%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Result for a=1
Result for b=0
Result for c=-1
Result for d=0
```

Only when the output is `1` the string is in the good format (because exactly one format specifier was matched and exactly one was in the `/dev/video%d` pattern in `sscanf`)